# Laplace Transform equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, laplace-method

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqn3W.png)

Viewing the picture attached, can anybody tell me why $$-\frac{A}{s+a}*e^{-(s+a)*t}$$ suddenly becomes $$\frac{A}{s+a}$$
in this example? What happened to our exponential equation and why is our fraction now positive instead of negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because
$$ e^{-(s+a)t}\bigg|_{t=\infty}=\lim_{t\to\infty} e^{-(s+a)t}=0.$$
Update: Using
$$ \int e^{ax}dx=\frac1a e^{ax}+C $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
F(s)&=&A\int_0^\infty e^{-(s+a)t}\\
&=&-\frac{A}{s+a}e^{-(s+a)t}\bigg|_{t=0}^\infty\\
&=&-\frac{A}{s+a}\bigg[\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-(s+a)t}-1\bigg]\\
&=&\frac{A}{s+a}
\end{eqnarray}
if $s+a>0$.

Comment: It is my humble opinion, but I think this should be a comment.

Comment: @xpaul Could you perhaps elaborate a bit on your answer. I do not quite understand.

Comment: @NemanjaVuksanovic please see the update.

Comment: @xpaul I did, thanks! Would the answer ALWAYS be positive?

Comment: Yes, that is right.